# Are color names supposed to work for codepen CSS?

Tags: css, codepen

I am using codepen and when I use color names in CSS, it doesn't apply unless I type "solid" in front of the color name.

For example, this works:

```css
h1 {border-bottom:3px solid black;}
```

And this does not:

```css
h1 {border-bottom:3px black;}
```

Is it supposed to work like this? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I think the second argument is border type only. You will have to give solid. You can try border-color prop else.

Answer (score 1):

`border-bottom` is a **shorthand property** that sets the value of:

- `border-bottom-width`
- `border-bottom-style`
- `border-bottom-color`

If you omit any of them, they'll take their initial value as defined by the specs. For `border-*-style` that's `none` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom-style#formal_definition)).

To verify the other properties are being applied, you can override `none` at a later stage:

```css
h1 {
    border-bottom: 15px green;
    border-bottom-style: double;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `border-bottom`, `border-left`, `border-right`, `border-top`, border is first you add `border-width` then `border-color` then `border-style` i.e. (1px solid black)

Comment: Your example `1px solid black` is correct but your statement preceding it has the order wrong — you say "border-width then **border-color** then border-style" which would be `1px black solid` which is incorrect.

Comment: I Don't Know About Codepen but on Text Editors like Visual Studio Code or Atom the order does not matter it works with the correct syntax

Comment: _"This is a shorthand property for setting the width, style, and color"_ — CSS Spec [§ 3.4. Border Shorthand Properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#border-shorthands) / _"The border shorthand CSS property sets an element's border. It sets the values of border-width, border-style, and border-color."_ — [MDN "border"](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/border) — it's not the text editors, it's the browsers being lenient about a mistake, and you _should not_ depend on such _unspecified behavior_.

Answer (score 0):

The border-style property, your `solid`, is a required property. Without setting a border-style the rest of the border won't render. See the documentation from [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp):

`Note: None of the OTHER CSS border properties (which you will learn more about in the next chapters) will have ANY effect unless the border-style property is set!`

There are more border style options that are available. One of these must be used for a border to be rendered:

```css
.dotted {border-style: dotted;}
.dashed {border-style: dashed;}
.solid {border-style: solid;}
.double {border-style: double;}
.groove {border-style: groove;}
.ridge {border-style: ridge;}
.inset {border-style: inset;}
.outset {border-style: outset;}
.none {border-style: none;}
.hidden {border-style: hidden;}
.mix {border-style: dotted dashed solid double;}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom), only one border property is required when using the `border` shorthand syntax. However, the `border-style` defaults to `none`, which is why your border doesn't appear if you don't specify `solid`.

Answer (score 0):

`Solid` here specify the style of the border it also has various type of style such as:

```
    border-style: dotted;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-style: solid;
    border-style: double;
    border-style: groove;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-style: inset;
    border-style: outset;
    border-style: none;
    border-style: hidden;
```

> **NOTE :** if you don't apply the style type of border it will not apply to elements.